# Asterisk 1.8 Dial cmd with g option

Tags: asterisk, pbx

Asterisk Dial pLan with (g) option

Hello I am attempting to log a call on completion the dial-plan is massive and has contingencies
If (callagent) is not answered it continues down the dial-plan however if the call is answered I need to upon completion of that call jump to (logresult).

As I understand it I can use Dial option (g) to come back to dial-plan. I need to set a variable letting me know that the call was connected So I can add logic and I am not sure how to determine if that call was answered in the dial plan.

Any Help Appreciated.
Asterisk 1.8

```
    exten => 1234,1(agent),PlayBack(shortly)
    exten => 1234,n,Ringing
    exten => 1234,n(callagent),Dial(SIP/backup2/${qryresult},12,g,)
    exten => 1234,n,PlayBack(busyagents)
    exten...... Lots more
    exten => 1234,n(Logresult),SET(qryresult1=${ODBC_MSSQLProc(${CALLERID(num)},${CHANNEL})})
     exten => 1234,n,Hangup()
```

Answer (score 1):

Dial command set DIALSTATUS variable for that.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+variable+DIALSTATUS